# Python logging configuration like Java log4j

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, configuration, log4j

I'm a Java developer who has transitioned to Python 3 development. I need to configure logging in my Python application, and I'd like to do it in a similar way to how I configured log4j in Java. Ideally I want my Python logging configuration file to be in YAML format. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a comprehensive answer to this question. I eventually figured it out and will share my solution here.

My YAML formatted logging configuration file looks like this (*I don't log to a file, so I commented out that part*):

```
---
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define format of output logs (named 'simple').
formatters:
    #simple:
    #    format: "XXX %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    console_formatter:
        format: "%(asctime)s | %(levelname)8s | %(name)50s | %(funcName)50s | %(message)s"

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REFERENCE: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html
handlers:

    ## Create rotating file handler using 'simple' format.
    #file_handler:
    #    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    #    level: INFO
    #    formatter: simple
    #    filename: jims-fantastic-log-file.log
    #    maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
    #    backupCount: 5
    #    encoding: utf8

    # Create console handler
    console_handler:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        formatter: console_formatter

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The 'root' logger (parent of all other loggers) is treated as a special case in the logging configuration.
# Any settings for the root logger become the default settings for all other loggers.
# You can override those defaults by providing a configuration for any loggers that need one.
root:
    level: WARN
    # handlers: [file_handler, console_handler]
    handlers: [console_handler]

# Provider logger-specific configuration below.
# Must like log4j in Java, logger names are treated as a hierarchy. The developer will typically use their module
# names as logger names, so the top-level package is the 'parent' and all the subpackages are the 'children'.
loggers:

    mypackage:
        level: INFO
        propagate: False
        handlers: [console_handler]

    mypackage.childpkg1:
        level: WARNING
        propagate: False
        handlers: [console_handler]

    mypackage.childpkg2:
        level: DEBUG
        propagate: False
        handlers: [console_handler]
```

This is the function I defined for initializing logging in my app. It just loads the YAML file:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml


def initialize_logging(path_to_logging_config_yaml_file):
    # Initialize the logger once as the application starts up.
    with open(path_to_logging_config_yaml_file, 'rt') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)

    # Get an instance of the logger and use it to write a log!
    # Note: Do this AFTER the config is loaded above or it won't use the config.
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Configured the logger!")
```

Reference to the tutorial I used to learn this:

- https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2018/11/26/logging-in-python-3-like-java-log4j-logback/